# Have all @PostConstruct called before getters

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In JSF2, I need a bean ClassA to be updated by ClassB during the PostConstruct,
and then display the updated value.
My problem is that the getter of ClassA is called before ClassB is PostConstructed.

The output I have:
ValX:
ValY: toto
ValX: 42

The output I want:
ValX: 42
ValY: toto
ValX: 42

Is it normal that all beans are not created before the view id built ?

What would be the proper solution to obtain to have ClassA updated before its getters are called ?

```java
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClassA implements Serializable {
    private String valX;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init ClassA");
    }

    public String getValX() {
        System.out.println("get ValX");
        return valX;
    }

    public void setValX(String valX) {
        System.out.println("set ValX");
        this.valX = valX;
    }
}
```

```js
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClassB implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{classA}")
    private ClassA classA;
    private String valY = "toto";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init ClassB");
        classA.setValX("42");
    }

    public ClassA getClassA() {
        return classA;
    }

    public void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    public String getValY() {
        return valY;
    }

    public void setValY(String valY) {
        this.valY = valY;
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        ValX: #{classA.valX}<br/>
        ValY: #{classB.valY}<br/>
        ValX: #{classA.valX}<br/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but why on earth would you want that? If you explain the use-case someone can probably give you an alternative that is less of a code smell. And on your point: JSF parses your xhtml and makes objects representing your EL-expressions out of them. They get evaluated at a different time and in no guaranteed order.

Comment: @mabi: In facts ClassA is used to display errors that happened during initialization of other beans. It is part of a xhtml file used by ui:composition, so it has no knowledge of other beans, but must be updated by them.

Comment: Does `classA` do anything that is not covered by a `FacesMessage`? You can use the omnifaces' [Messages](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages) helper to make adding new messages for the front-end pretty easily. If there's more logic to it, I'd add CDI events and have `classA` listen to them via `@Observe` an method.

Comment: I tried with messages, but if the o:messages tag is before ValY: #{classB.valY}, messages are considered as unhandled (and not displayed in production environment).  I did not test with CDI, but I think the update of the bean will be after the getter is called as if ClassB called classA.setValX().

Comment: The only thing you need to do is bind any property of ClassB before using ClassA's property

Answer (score 0):

> You can initialize the classB from the constructor of ClassA, so that
>   the post Constructor of classB will be called before the ClassA's
>   post constructor is called.

First an object of the class is created. ie the constructor is called.

Then the post constructor which is pinned with the class, as auto execute just after the object is created.

Any other function inside the class whether its a getter or a setter or a normal function, can only be called using the object that is already created.

If you want to call the function before the object of the class is created, then you must declare a function as static. In all the other ways the getter will be called

Comment: In my case ClassA has no knowledge on ClassB, because there may be multiple classes that do the thing, but not in all views. (I just added a comment to explain my use case)